# Adding a Unique ID To Each Array Element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js

**Problem:** I have destructured the array, and have a working component. However, when I offer the `key` prop with the `id`, I still obtain a warning.

**Warning:** `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of NestedList. It was passed a child from Faqs.`

**Expectation:** There not to be an error, as I have offered the key prop a value to the highest level of the return statement within the array mapping.

**Tech-stack:**

1. `"react": "^17.0.2"`,
2. `"next": "^9.5.1"`,

**Nested List Component Code:**
The `<Box key={id}>` has the id of each array element

```
import { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Divider, Typography, Box } from "@mui/material";

import {
  ListSubheader,
  List,
  ListItemButton,
  ListItemText,
  ListItemIcon,
  Collapse,
} from "@mui/material";
import ExpandLess from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";

import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const NestedList = ({ listTitle, classes, array}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(0);

  return (
    <List
      className={classes.Container}
      sx={{ bgcolor: "background.paper" }}
      aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
      subheader={
        <ListSubheader
          className={classes.ListSubheader}
          component="div"
          id="nested-list-subheader"
        >
          <Typography variant="h1">{listTitle}</Typography>
        </ListSubheader>
      }
    >
      {array.map(({ id, question, answer }) => (
        <Box key={id}>
          <ListItemButton
            className={classes.ListItemButton}
            onClick={() => {
              setSelectedId(id);
              id !== selectedId ? setOpen(true) : setOpen(false);
            }}
          >
            <ListItemIcon className={classes.ListItemIcon}>
              {selectedId === id && open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText>
              <Typography variant="h3">{question}</Typography>
            </ListItemText>
          </ListItemButton>
          <Collapse in={id === selectedId && open} timeout={300} unmountOnExit>
            <List className={classes.List} component="div">
              <ListItemText className={classes.ListItemText} sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
                {answer}
              </ListItemText>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
          <Divider />
        </Box>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};

NestedList.proptypes = {
  listTitle: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  classes: PropTypes.object,
  array: PropTypes.array,
};

export default withStyles((theme) => ({
  Container: {
    padding: 48,
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 1200,
    color: "#50595a",
  },
  ListSubheader: {
    marginBottom: 16,
    color: "black",
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  ListItemButton: {
    width: "100%",
    padding: 8,
  },
  ListItemIcon: {
    minWidth: 30,
  },
  List: {
    padding: 0,
  },
  ListItemText: {
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
}))(NestedList);
```

The `Faqs` component, that uses the `NestedList` component:

```
import NestedList from "../../components/nestedList/nestedList";
import * as ROUTES from "../../public/routes";

const Faqs = () => {
  const array = [
    {
      id: 1,
      question: "Where can I learn more about teaching in China?",
      answer: [
        "We’ve put together a ",
        <a href={ROUTES.RESOURCES}>Resources Page</a>,
        " to answer your most frequent questions. From ",
        <a href={ROUTES.HOW_MUCH_MONEY_CAN_I_SAVE_IN_CHINA}>Saving Money</a>,
        " to ",
        <a href={ROUTES.WHAT_IS_THE_Z_VISA_PROCESS}>Getting Your Z-VISA</a>,
        " we have gone into detail there.",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      question: "How will I get my VISA?",
      answer: [
        "Your school will apply for your VISA for you to work directly for them. We’ll be with you every step of the journey. We’ve created our own ",
        <a href={ROUTES.WHAT_IS_THE_Z_VISA_PROCESS}>VISA Support Page</a>,
        ". Remember, the VISA you’re applying for is a Z-VISA.",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      question: "Who will I be employed by?",
      answer: [
        "You will be employed directly by a school. ",
        <a
          href={
            ROUTES.WHAT_IS_IT_LIKE_USING_A_RECRUITING_COMPANY_FOR_FINDING_SCHOOLS_IN_CHINA
          }
        >
          Learn more
        </a>,
        " about what it is like working with HiredinChina to find your teaching position.",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      question: "How long will my contract be?",
      answer: [
        "You will have a minimum of a one-year contract, that will be full-time. You can save a lot of money teaching in China, and we’ve put together ",
        <a href={ROUTES.HOW_MUCH_MONEY_CAN_I_SAVE_IN_CHINA}>
          more information for you to read
        </a>,
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      question: "What happens if I am ill?",
      answer:
        "When you are directly employed by the school, they will offer you insurance. This means private level care. Be sure to check your contract for sick days.",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      question: "Can I send money home?",
      answer: [
        "You will have to go through your bank to legitimately send money home. To do this, follow the steps they give you. Your school will help support you and will be able to translate anything you need.",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      question: "I can’t speak Chinese, is that a problem?",
      answer: [
        "That is fantastic news! Not speaking Chinese is great for your students, as you will be able to immerse them in English more. We’ve also put together an ",
        <a href={ROUTES.MANDARIN_PHRASE_GUIDE}>Essential Mandarin Guide</a>,
        " and ",
        <a href={ROUTES.IS_LEARNING_MANDARIN_IMPORTANT_FOR_LIVING_IN_CHINA}>
          Benefits For Learning Mandarin when you’re exploring.
        </a>,
      ],
    },
  ];
  return <NestedList listTitle="FAQS" array={array} />;
};

export default Faqs;
```

Comment: This way may bring you closer to the answer‍ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161825/react-material-ui-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop?rq=1

Comment: Hi @VidaHedayati, thank you for reaching out. I believe I've already added the key in the correct place, which is what this question is suggesting to do.

Comment: Hi @LukeP ,Please try this way: Use the ```<ListItem key={id}></ListItem>``` instead of ```<Box key={id}></Box>```